# Entity Framework 6 - Violation of PRIMARY KEY after get an Entity from Context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, primary-key

I'm studying EF6 with a test project. I have this class

```
public class Application
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual TCompany Company { get; set; } //Independent Association
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; protected set; }
}
```

And this company class

```
public class TCompany
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Application> Applications { get; private set; }
}
```

This is the code of the relationship

```
 private ApplicationMap()   {
        this.Map(m => {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Applications");
        });

        this.HasKey(a => a.Id);

        this.Property(a => a.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("ApplicationInvariantNameIndex") { IsUnique = true, Order = 1 }));

        this.HasMany(a => a.Users).WithMany(u => u.Applications)
        .Map(ua => {
            ua.MapLeftKey("ApplicationId");
                ua.MapRightKey("UserId");
                ua.ToTable("UserApplications");
            });


            /* Sorry previously i forget to ad this line of code */
            this.Map<HUBApplication>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(typeof(HUBApplication).FullName).HasMaxLength(64));

    }

    private CompanyMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Companies");
        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);

        this.Property(c => c.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("CompanyNameIndex") { IsUnique = true, Order = 1 }));

        this.HasMany(c => c.Applications).WithRequired(a => a.Company).Map(ac => {
            ac.MapKey("CompanyId");
            ac.HasColumnAnnotation("CompanyId", "Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_CompanyId") { IsUnique = false, Order = 1 }));
        });
    }
```

Now, into the DB I have done some inserts without problems.
But my code throws an exception of "primary key violation" when I try to retrieve an `Application` from the DB and then do some stuff.
For easier debugging, I wrote this simple code to understand what happens:

```
Application app = this.EFContext.Set<Application>().Find(Guid.Parse("5dc780a3-768a-4e14-b55f-640d3b69e9b2"));
this.EFContext.SaveChanges(); //EXCEPTION!!
```

In this code, I retrieve the `Application` from DB, and the `Application` has the `Company` property properly set with the `Company` object that is associated with the `Application` in the DB.

But when I call `SaveChanges()` without changing anything, it throws this exception:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Companies'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Companies'. The duplicate key value is (28efac4c-b61c-43a7-a8df-146afba87bde).
>   The statement has been terminated.

For greater clarity this is my `DbContext` class

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : this("DefaultConnection")
    {  }

    public DataContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {  }

    public DataContext(DbConnection existingConnection, DbCompiledModel model, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, model, contextOwnsConnection)
    { }

    public DataContext(DbCompiledModel model)
        : base(model)
    { }

    public DataContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    { }

    public DataContext(string nameOrConnectionString, DbCompiledModel model)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString, model)
    {  }

    public virtual IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual IDbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }

    public virtual IDbSet<TCompany> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(ApplicationMap.Mapping); //posted above
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(UserMap.Mapping);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(CompanyMap.Mapping); //posted above
    }
}
```

Then this `DbContext` is a property of a UnitTest class in this way

```
public abstract class EntityFrameworkUnitTestBase : UnitTestBase
{
    private readonly DataContext _dbContext;

    public DataContext EFContext { get { return this._dbContext; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contructor
    /// </summary>
    public EntityFrameworkUnitTestBase()
    {
        this._dbContext = new DataContext(base.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Well this is the complete test code

```
[TestClass]
public class UserEntityTest : UserTestBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CRUDUser_Test()
    {
        IdentityApplication app = this.EFContext.Set<IdentityApplication>().Find(Guid.Parse("5dc780a3-768a-4e14-b55f-640d3b69e9b2"));
        this.EFContext.SaveChanges(); //EXCEPTION!!!
    }
}

public abstract class UserTestBase : EntityFrameworkUnitTestBase
{
    //{...} some properties
    protected UserTestBase()
    { }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: Are the two lines you posted where you retrieve the `Application` via `Find` and then call `SaveChanges()` the only lines? Where do you open the EFContext? Can you try wrapping those lines in a `using( var context = new MyContext()) {...}` block?

Comment: It seems the SaveChanges() is inserting a new company but with the code you provided we cannot see how this could happen.

Comment: Could you show `EFContext` class and update method?

Comment: thanks for your answer @Sentry i have updated the question post as requested

Comment: Now i have figured out what is the problem, even if I did not fully understand the cause. `Application` is a base class... The `Application` which i retrieve with `Find` method is a derived sealed class`HUBApplication`. The `sealed` keyword is responsible for throwing the exception. But now i don't know why...